# How do I approach this regression problem

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks

I want to estimate a monthly released financial value between 0 and 150. To do so, I have lots of daily stock data.

What would be a good way to use the information of the temporal evolution in my regression? I obviously could compute the average of all days in a month, but I would lose a lot of information.

Lets say I'd use a NN for the regression (btw: is this a good idea?). How do I incorporate 30/31 different data vectors to predict a single value?

I hope i made somewhat clear what my problem is. If not, let me know and I will try to edit my question.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would depend a great deal on what your prior beliefs/hypotheses are about what might be the cause and effect.

For instance, if your monthly dependent variable were corporate profits for the month, and each company put out daily estimates that they fine-tuned as the month went on, then the last day's data is probably the really useful one: it is the ultimate refined answer after all 30 or 31 days are known for all firms, and no more estimates are being made.

If the daily variables were a daily profits report for each firm, you probably want to add them all (30 or 31 - or 28) since that would/should add to the monthly report.

Those are extreme, and there are cases where a weighted sum, average, or many other things might make the most sense.  But you can't really say without knowing more about the hypothesis you already have and what the data is.